# Java: Store int in Integer array

Tags: java, arrays

Can you store int values into a Integer array?

Given an array:

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[10];
```

Are the following two statements equivalent?

```
Integer x = new Integer(1);
array[0] = x;

int x = 1;
array[0] = x;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not 100% equivalent. The following should be equivalent however:

```
Integer x = Integer.valueOf(1); 
array[0] = x;

int x = 1; 
array[0] = x;
```

Note that the int primitive gets [autoboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to the Integer wrapper class. So you're not storing an int primitive in the Integer array, but an Integer object.

You should hardly ever use the Integer constructor (which always creates a new object) but use one of its static factory methods or autoboxing (less code), which allow to cache instances (since they are immutable).

Answer (score 0):

Once the values are inside the array itself, they are both values of type `Integer`. If you pass a primitive object to an instance of its wrapper class, then that primitive type is *autoboxed*, meaning its automatically converted to the type of its wrapper class.

```
Integer x = 4; //autoboxing: "4" is converted to "new Integer(4)"
```

Likewise, a wrapper class type can is *unboxed* when it is passed to a primitive type:

```
int x = new Integer(4); //unboxing: "new Integer(4)" is converted to primitive int 4
```

For your purposes, both examples your wrote will work.